# Pause a function on hover of an element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been working with some javascript code which is from codepen, I forked it for my own usage and added some code to auto rotate the outer circle.

What I am unable to do is modify the code to pause on the shown element when I hover over the centre element .circle--rotate

The code I am working with for myself is on https://codepen.io/CelticWebs/pen/oNMxdrK. To attempt to do what I wanted, auto animate as well as pass eon hover, I added the following code at line 111 in the javascript:

```
function movetheone() {
  i.is(":animated") || (p.direction = "right", p.step = d, o())
}
let abc = setInterval(movetheone, 3000);
$('.circle--rotate').hover(() => {
  clearInterval(abc);
}, () => {
  movetheone
})
```

This spins the circle automatically, then does stop spinning when you hover over it but unfortunately it often moves forward one place before pausing, which make the hover pointless as it moves away from what you wanted to stop on.  It also doesn't start back up when you move away.

Does anybody have any suggestions on making this work better please?

I've made the link to the code more obvious above for those asking for more of the code.  Thanks.

Comment: Why are all your variables and functions just one letter? It's impossible to understand code like this.

Comment: Please see [ask], then provide some HTML along with your code in a snippet demo using the editor.

Comment: Does your wheel have n different segments? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example as it's impossible to know what a solution may be without seeing your HTML structure and a bit more information on what your requirement is.

Comment: @ isherwood and @AHaworth, thanks for the response. The code was there in an editor for people to see, I've made the link more obvious in the description now.  All html, css and javascript is there.

Thanks again for your responses.

Comment: Please put code into your question, not an external site. Have a good read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example There is a good reason for asking for this as SO is trying to build up a question and answer bank that will be useful to future readers and your codepen could be deleted some time, rendering the question useless.